# Unable to read the license file `../LICENSE` for the spec `integration_test

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, flutter-dependencies

I use Flutter with Android studio and when I run

The Error output from CocoaPods is shown as below

Do you know how to solve the problem?

[Screen shot of Android studio]
[image]

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 8 in debug mode...

Running pod install...

CocoaPods' output:

↳

```
  Preparing
```

.
.
.
.
.

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

```
[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

[!] A license was specified in podspec `integration_test` but the file does not exist - /Users/a/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app5/ios/.symlinks/plugins/integration_test/LICENSE

[!] Unable to read the license file `../LICENSE` for the spec `integration_test (0.0.1)`

[!] Unable to read the license file `../LICENSE` for the spec `integration_test (0.0.1)`
```

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 8.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue. The first of them I was able to solve:
open your project's `Podfile` which is located in your project's `ios` folder and remove the comments in line 2 to e.g.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

First at all, if you use flutter in `dev` or `beta` channel, should change it to `master` or `stable`.

If not, to resolve first issue, open `ios/Podfile` and uncomment second line

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

to resolve another issues which relative with `integration_test`, a simple way is just remove it, open `pubspec.yaml`, remove below code

```
integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

and give it a try.